# PHPMyAdmin (WAMP)

Tags: php, wamp, phpmyadmin

I haven't been able to find the answer to this question, but I have a local MySQL database running on my computer using WAMP, and I have a table with over 30k rows in it. I'm trying to query the row count for that table, but it only returns 1,000 for the result. That's across all tables (all that have more than 1,000 rows).

I'm looking for the setting I need to change for this. One of my tables has 500,000 rows in it, so that is my most extreme case. At first, I thought this was a PHP issue, but even when running the query directly in PHPMyAdmin, it return the same 1,000 rows. Thank you for your help.

Comment: what was the query you used to count rows?
and did you try to query all records in php and count the result for test sake ?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said count rows. If I do a select all query against the table (SELECT * FROM Student) with more than 1,000 rows in it, it only returns 1,000 (without me setting a limit in the query) rows/results.

Comment: i just made a test and added 50000 records and it shown just fine. 
https://ibb.co/8jHkrH6  Server version: 5.6.17 phpmyadmin: 4.8.2
it could be a setting in my.ini ( mysql ) but i don't know for sure if there is